# How do we extract ftp client information from proftpd logs

Tags: linux, ftp, logging

using proftpd 1.3.4. Needs to see which FTP client is being used by end user any idea where it will be logged. or what configuration changes it will need

Comment: The question is clear enough. and was given satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTTP you have the User-Agent header. With FTP there is no such thing, which means that the server is not able to find out the client software and thus can not log it.

Comment: FYI, more and more FTP clients are using the non-standard [`CLNT`](http://www.serv-u.com/respcode.asp?prod=s&cmd=CLNT) command for sending client information to the server; sort of a `User-Agent` equivalent for FTP.